# ffmpeg is not being detected by Spyder

Tags: ffmpeg, spyder, openai-gym

Running almost every code from OpenAi gym in spyder by Anaconda (for instance this code: https://gym.openai.com/evaluations/eval_y5dnhk0ZSMqlqJKBz5vJQw )
I run into the following error message:

```
DependencyNotInstalled: Found neither the ffmpeg nor avconv executables. On OS X, you can install ffmpeg via 'brew install ffmpeg'. On most Ubuntu variants, 'sudo apt-get install ffmpeg' should do it. On Ubuntu 14.04, however, you'll need to install avconv with 'sudo apt-get install libav-tools'.
```

However when I type `brew install ffmpeg` in terminal, I get `Warning: ffmpeg-3.2 already installed` and nothing happens.

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install a copy of ffmpeg that can be recognized by Anaconda. Please run this command in a terminal to do that

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

Comment: can i do this through pip on windows somehow? I installed ffmpeg with pip but it doessnt seem to work

Comment: If you install ffmpeg with pip, it means you installed the Python bindings for ffmpeg, not the ffmpeg package itself.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my problem by placing actual ffmpeg.exe file in the directory of my project. Now everything works fine

Comment: Also works fine for me after adding `ffmpeg` to path. See http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/

Comment: @CGFoX, a lot of bad things can come up from that (like strange and unexpected segfaults), so that's not the best idea.

Comment: Why's that? Do you refer to adding `ffmpeg` to path or to installing it manually?

Comment: To adding it to PATH, because the libraries that ffmpeg depends on are most probably not binary compatible with the ones provided by Anaconda.

Comment: CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\keramatfar\Anacon
da3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.

Comment: That could be solved by restarting your computer, but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download and install `ffmpeg` and then add to path. After restarting the Jupyter notebook server, it worked for me.

See full instructions here: http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/

Comment: For me, when doing this, the error disappears but I get an 1kb sized video file that won't play using VLC. Any tips or tricks?

Comment: There was a bug in the OpenAI library (see here https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1925 ). I fixed it manually and now it runs like a charm. This answer works for me.